# Designing a game advice

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

I'm trying to design a game which is similar to Plague Inc. and it is essentially where there is a deadly virus (quite ironic) which is spreading and the aim of the game is to stop the virus from spreading.

I've split the world into 13 regions, and each region will have several key details I will need to use, such as the number of cases, the number of deaths and the population. With each of these details, I will want some of them to be dynamic, such as wanting the amount of cases and deaths to go up or down.

I'm extremely new to python, and was hoping for some particular expertise in how to design this game. Any guidance of the best ways to represent this data would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hello Aran Khalastchi,

Based off of my experiences, Python is not really a *graphical* programming language, and more of a text based language. I wouldn't suggest Python as your go to unless you are using a library for graphics. If not, I definitely recommend Unity or Godot, and if you want to go fully raw code (no engines/libraries) I recommend Java as it has its own graphics. If I am wrong, please forgive me :)